# getnameinfo's signature changes between glibc versions, how can I match it?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, posix

I need to match the signature for the call [getnameinfo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/getnameinfo.html) so I can write a wrapper around that call. Unfortunately the signature changes between hosts.

Things were working and going find until I tried to compile on the latest CentOS, 6.3, which gives the error:

```
error: conflicting types for 'getnameinfo'
```

Huh?

It turns out that the final argument, flags, is listed as an unsigned int on CentOS (glibc-headers-2.12-1.80) but is just an int on Fedora (glibc-headers-2.15-58).  (Note that the man pages on both hosts say it should be an int.)

```
extern int getnameinfo ( /*cut*/, unsigned int __flags);
```

vs

```
extern int getnameinfo ( /*cut*/, int __flags);
```

Some searching leads me to believe that [the standard has changed the type](http://marc.info/?l=netbsd-tech-net&m=102208795729161) of the flags argument.

It looks like I need to change the type of flags in my function to match the host's definition. 
What's the best way to deal with this problem? Is this an autoconf-type issue or is there some simpler solution? I hoped that the compiler (gcc) would have some macro I could leverage but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could check the `__GLIBC_MINOR__` macro defined in `features.h` and pass the arguments accordingly, example:

```
#include <features.h>

#if __GLIBC_MINOR__ > 12 
    getnameinfo(..., flags);
#else 
    getnameinfo(..., (unsigned) flags);
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks. It's actually the opposite, > 12 should have nothing, but the jist was right. How'd you find out about __ GLIBC_MINOR __?

Comment: @PaulRubel I read about them somewhere can't really remember :) there's also a `__GLIBC__` for the major version.